# Power BI - control the drill up behaviour in matrix

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, dax

I am having data such that multiple currencies are present in single column[image]

As one can see above in the Vested Value column , Now I needed subtotals currency wise but since I am appending the currency symbols alongside values , therefore the datatype of columns is text , so cannot use automatic subtotals. So , I precalculated the subtotal and inserted it as  a row inside the table as you can see the "SUBtotal-YEN" row . but since these are text formats , so when I drill up , it gives wrong answers. Thats why I need to cutomise the drill behaviour.Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: So in your source table is the value column a text format or it that just how you are displaying it?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes the column shown is in text format , as power bi allows column level formatting for only a single currency format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating an explicit measure instead of using the automatic implicit measure. If your `VestedValue` column is numeric, then you can use the following measure to get the subtotals working as well. (The currency formatting is done after the summing happens.)

```
VestedMeasure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(TableName[Home Currency]),
    "USD",FORMAT(SUM(TableName[VestedValue]),"$#,##0"),
    "YEN",FORMAT(SUM(TableName[VestedValue]),"¥#,##0"))
```

If that column is not numeric, then create a calculated column that is and use that in the measure instead. The following formula strips off the currency symbol and converts to a numeric value:

```
VestedNumeric = VALUE(RIGHT(TableName[VestedValue], LEN(TableName[VestedValue])-1))
```

Comment: Hi its still not working , the vested measure is coming out to be empty column having blank  rows

Comment: actually there are further columns to the left of "Home currency" such as "user". So I need to show currency subtotals and then on drill up , it should display user totals and there is a further drill up also there. Basically , there is a heirarchy present and I want to show subtotals at each level . So , if I use the format function , wouldn't it make it a text and cause problem in further drilling up

Comment: @kartik Did you try it using the calculated column instead of the VestedValue like I suggested?

Comment: Yes Alexis , I have a sperate column with values of vasted column with the datatype whole numbers. I tried vested measure on that

Comment: also, format function returns a string , so even I get the correct format here, how will it provide the right values , when I drill up?

Comment: My bad , I was doing it incorrectly . Now , it seems to be working. In future I probably would be using direct queries in powerbi . Will this measure still hold good then???

Comment: @kartik I don't see any reason the query type would affect your measure.